# Let the last <td> in a <tr> behave like a new row

Tags: html, css

is it possible to let the last < td > in a < tr > behave like a completly new row without using any jQuery or javaScript stuff?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>normal td</td>
  <td>normal td</td>
  <td>normal td</td>
  <td class="i-want-to-be-a-row">row content</td>
 </tr>
```

In this example i want that the td with "i-want-to-be-a-row" behave like a new row.

I tried something like that:

```
.i-want-to-be-a-row {
 display:block;
}
```

But i think that this is the wrong way ;)

Comment: How do you expect it to behave like a row while it's still _in_ a `tr`?

Comment: Using flexbox, should be a good ideia - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @LuisP.A.: _"I wan to get from A to B"_ - _"Use a vehicle"_. I don't really see how flexbox can make that `td` break out of the `tr`, though.

Comment: @cerbrus - check this out -> https://jsfiddle.net/v6n1wLby/1/

Comment: @LuisP.A.: That's nifty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using flexbox (much cleaner):

**CSS**

```
table, tbody, tr, td {
    display: block;
}
tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
td {
    flex: 1 0 30%;
    border: solid 1px green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>normal td</td>
        <td>normal td</td>
        <td>normal td</td>
        <td class="i-want-to-be-a-row">row content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/v6n1wLby/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put it in a new row?

```
<tr>
  <td>normal td</td>
  <td>normal td</td>
  <td>normal td</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">row content</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That would be the easiest solution ;-) But in my case this isn't possible. The < td > must be in the same row like the other 3 < td >'s